# How to log device connection/disconnection information on Windows 8.1?

Tags: usb, windows-8.1

My Windows 8.1 desktop is always on (not even sleep). However, when I move the mouse/press the keyboard to turn on the display and then unlock the user, I get Device Disconnect sounds from Windows. This can happen 0 to 10 times one after another and then just stops by itself -- until the next time I "wake" the computer (not from sleep but from screensaver/display-off).

A [previous question asks about Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/366888/which-windows-7-log-file-contains-device-connection-disconnection-information) and the answer is to get USBLogView. But USBLogView is not compatible with Windows 8. Any other solutions?

Looking at Device Manager just shows it refreshing every time I hear the sound, but I don't see any changes in the devices.

Comment: This answer might help: https://superuser.com/a/1695767/249349

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case someone sees this down the line and needs an answer. I finally found something useful.

[EventGhost](http://www.eventghost.org/) shows a log of all USB device connections and disconnections. Fully compatibly with my Windows 8.1 PC.

Comment: Just here to confirm this still works on Windows 10. EventGhost just helped me troubleshoot a Windows update BSOD loop that I've been dragging for 2 years now.