# powershell : how to detect an uninstalled usb device?

Tags: usb, powershell, events

I would like my Powershell script to detect when I plug in a usb device. I have set the GPOs to block the automatic installation of usb devices.

For now I am using this command to detect when a usb device is plugged in :

```
$query = SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_LogicalDisk' AND TargetInstance.DriveYpe=23


Register-WmiEvent -Query $query -SourceIdentifier RemovableDiskDetection -Action {...}
```

But probably because the device isn't installed, the event is not detected and nothing happens.
What sort of query should I use to detect when a usb device is plugged in even if the driver of the usb device are not yet installed on the machine ?

Comment: There are USB devices other than mass storage devices though? What exactly did you block and what exactly are you trying to see? Unless the GPO malfunctions, a drive device won’t appear.

Comment: No there is no other USB device besides my USB key. 
I enabled the GPO "Prevent installation of removable devices " and "Prevent installation of devices not described by other policy settings."
I want to register a Powershell event that will detect when I plug a usb device is plugged in and will display a message, for example "USB detected". This works well when the GPO are not enabled but I do not want usb devices to be autmatically installed.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this question is a near enough duplicate to the question here: [Where can I find logs on recent USB insertion in the Event Viewer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1096887/where-can-i-find-logs-on-recent-usb-insertion-in-the-event-viewer)