# Scheduling an event based on USB device connect/disconnect in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, event-log

I have two PCs and a single set of peripherals between them. Whenever I want to switch PCs, I have to swap the monitor input, change audio source and switch over my peripherals by pressing a button on my USB switch. All but the last one can be done via software, so I'd like to condense the process down to just pressing a button.

The idea is to create a scheduled event that would trigger when a USB device (the 4-port USB switch) is disconnected. According to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1096887/where-can-i-find-logs-on-recent-usb-insertion-in-the-event-viewer/1137451), these events are not logged by Windows, but can be captured by external programs. Is there any way to produce a Windows event from something like USBLogView?

Comment: Have you checked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/219401/starting-scheduled-task-by-detecting-connection-of-usb-device)? It is a bit old but the involved subsystems have not changed that much in the last 10 years.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Robert. The question sadly doesn't have an applicable answer, as they all deal with an external drive being connected. That particular operation does have a corresponding Windows event, while other generic USB devices seemingly do not.

Comment: Then you may have to write a small tool on your own that waits for the USB device events and executes the command you want when the correct USB device event is recognized: The following project seems to be usable even if it also focuses on drives later but the first part should work: https://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/detecting-usb-devices-using-c.html