# Where to get more information on "USB Device Not Recognized" error?

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb

I have a particular USB 2.0 device. When I plug it on my Windows 10 PC, it **always** shows this message:

[image]

Then, after few seconds, the device starts working normally. I would like to debug this issue. Does Windows provide more debugging information about this event?

Comment: You could look in the Event Viewer. Questions: (1) Is it happening only with one USB device? (2) Only on one USB port? (3) Only with one USB cable?

Comment: Which particular section of Event Viewer should I see? It is happening only with that particular device. Tried on every USB port of my Notebook. Also tried changing the cable.

Comment: See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1096887/where-can-i-find-logs-on-recent-usb-insertion-in-the-event-viewer) and its linked duplicate.

Comment: USB devices are complicated.  `a particular USB 2.0 device` is not helpful.  USB devices can represent themselves as one of several classes (like print, mouse, etc) and there is a type for vendor defined 0xFF.  Most devices will show up as one of the built in types and use a built-in driver.  0xFF devices need a specific driver from the vendor.  I am guessing that your device isn't working and not the system it is being installed on but without knowing WHAT device, these guesses are pointless.