# Which Windows event is generated for external USB storage mounted as a disk volume?

Tags: windows, logging, usb-storage, event-log, events

What is the Windows event generated when an external USB storage is mounted as a disk volume in the OS?

Events like PnP events are triggered even if the external USB storage drive is blocked by AD group policy. I want the event to be triggered only when the USB storage is successfully mounted as a disk volume in Windows.

Comment: Event ID 2003? https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-track-down-usb-flash-drive-usage-in-windows-10s-event-viewer/

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1096887/where-can-i-find-logs-on-recent-usb-insertion-in-the-event-viewer

Comment: Are you looking for all disk mount events, USB storage device connection, or something else? Please edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Hi, I have made my question more clear now