# Windows 7 plug and play log file

Tags: windows-7

Sometime, I have the plug-and-play noise popping up randomly, but I can't find why it does that.

I was wondering if there was a way to get a log file or an event file to see everything that happened related to plug-and-play (or maybe something else, why not).

Thanks

Comment: Windows Event Logger!?

Comment: Also see: [Windows keeps making these random “device connect” and “device disconnect” sounds](http://superuser.com/questions/125377/windows-keeps-making-these-random-device-connect-and-device-disconnect-sound)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find all the information in Windows Event Viewer. I am not sure but i think the Plug and Play Logfile Location is `%WINDIR%\Inf\Setupapi*.log`  .Read the  Windows documentation [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744583%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for more information.

---

NirSoft has some very useful tools, you could try also [USBLogView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_log_view.html)