# Random keyboard delays and sounds

Tags: windows-8, audio, keyboard

Within the last few days, my workstation has acquired a new 'feature'.

Symptoms:

- keyboard entry is stopped for a few seconds
- the active window looses focus
- the `device disconnect` (Windows Hardware Remove.wav) sound is played
- situation repeats every 10 seconds or so

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/125377/windows-keeps-making-these-random-device-connect-and-device-disconnect-sound) was helpful in identifying the sound, but not the resolution.

I have a number of applications running:

- WSL2
- Docker for Windows
- Cisco AnyConnect
- McAfee
- Edge

Any ideas on the cause or solution?

** edit 0 **

rebooting doesn't fix the problem.

** edit 1 **

I'm using process monitor with a filter on `Windows Hardware Remove.wav` to capture the events.

For some reason, Explorer.EXE is repeatedly generating a series of events:

- `CreateFile - Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened`
- `QueryStandardInfomationFile - AllocationSize: 106,496, EndOfFile: 105,876, NumberOfLinks: 2, DeletePending: False, Directory: False`
- `QueryBasicInfomationFile - CreationTime: 12/7/2019 3:08:07 AM, LastAccessTime: 12/10/2021 12:07:00 PM, LastWriteTime: 12/7/2019 3:08:07 AM, ChangeTime: 4/21/2021 2:23:47 PM, FileAttributes: A`
- `CloseFile`

Is this reasonable?

Comment: Look in *Task Manger* Details pane for what is using CPU an I/O heavily... could be a slow app, could be malware or a crypto-miner. However, I would not bother to fix that... just install a modern OS.

Comment: I don't have the rights to reimage a corporate resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use an [IO Gear's Compact USB-C Docking Station with PD Pass-Thru](https://www.iogear.com/product/GUD3C03) to connect these to my HP Elitebook laptop:

- Apple Magic Keyboard
- Verbatim mouse
- RG6 network cable
- USB for Apple monitor's audio
- minidisplay port for Apple monitor's video

It appears that having the USB keyboard connected to the USB hub was responsible for the continuous plug/unplug events ([USBLogView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_log_view.html)):

```
Event Type  Event Time  Device Name Description Device Type Drive Letter    Serial Number   Vendor ID   Product ID  Vendor Name Product Name    Firmware Revision   USB Class   USB SubClass    USB Protocol    
Unplug  2/10/2022 10:36:53 AM   Port_#0002.Hub_#0004    USB Composite Device    Unknown         05ac    024f    Apple, Inc.     0.74    00  00  00  
Unplug  2/10/2022 10:36:53 AM   0000.0014.0000.005.004.002.000.000.000  USB Input Device    HID (Human Interface Device)            05ac    024f    Apple, Inc.     0.74    03  01  01  
Unplug  2/10/2022 10:36:53 AM   0000.0014.0000.005.004.002.000.000.000  USB Input Device    HID (Human Interface Device)            05ac    024f    Apple, Inc.     0.74    03  00  00  
Unplug  2/10/2022 10:36:53 AM   Port_#0004.Hub_#0005    Generic USB Hub Unknown     MSFT20000000000000  05ac    1006    Apple, Inc. Hub in Aluminum Keyboard    96.15   00  00  00  
Plug    2/10/2022 10:36:56 AM   Port_#0002.Hub_#0002    Generic USB Hub Unknown     MSFT20000000000000  05ac    1006    Apple, Inc. Hub in Aluminum Keyboard    96.15   00  00  00  
Plug    2/10/2022 10:37:11 AM   Port_#0002.Hub_#0004    USB Composite Device    Unknown         05ac    024f    Apple, Inc.     0.74    00  00  00  
Plug    2/10/2022 10:37:11 AM   0000.0014.0000.002.002.000.000.000.000  USB Input Device    HID (Human Interface Device)            05ac    024f    Apple, Inc.     0.74    03  01  01  
Plug    2/10/2022 10:37:11 AM   0000.0014.0000.002.002.000.000.000.000  USB Input Device    HID (Human Interface Device)            05ac    024f    Apple, Inc.     0.74    03  00  00
```

I have the keyboard connected directly to the laptop and no recurring events have occurred.

Relevant: [Windows keeps making these random "device connect" and "device disconnect" sounds](https://superuser.com/questions/125377/windows-keeps-making-these-random-device-connect-and-device-disconnect-sound)

Comment: I purchased a [HyperDrive USB Type C Hub Dongle](https://www.hypershop.com/collections/usb-c-hubs/products/hyperdrive-slim-usb-c-hub-for-macbook-chromebook-pc-usb-c-devices).  It works without any of the issues associated with the IO Gear device.